# An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am attempting to encrypt some data where my table has half a million records. Inspired by the answer here - [Fastest Way of Inserting in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940225/fastest-way-of-inserting-in-entity-framework) - I attempted to chunk up my update by calling a recursive function:

```
IDBContext context;
try{
    context = new MyDbContext();
    context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
    EncryptFields(context, 500, (count / 500));
}
finally{
   if (context != null)
   {
       context.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Recursive function here:

```
private static void EncryptFields(IDBContext context, int batchSize, int maxRetries)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(maxRetries.ToString());
        if (maxRetries == 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        var phones = context.Phones
                            .Where(p => !(p.Number == null 
                                       || p.Number.Trim() == String.Empty))
                            .Take(batchSize)
                            .ToList();

        if (phones.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (var phone in phones)
            {
                phone.Enc_Number = Encrypt(phone.Number);
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
            context.Dispose();
            context = new MyDBContext();
            context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

            EncryptFields(context, batchSize, --maxRetries);
        }
    }
```

I started off with a `maxRetry` value of 1270, but when it dropped to 360, I got a StackOverflow exception on the line:

```
var phones = context.Phones...
```

Given I dispose of the context and re-create it after updating every 500 records, I'm unsure why I am getting this exception.

Comment: This exception is not caused by EF. It is caused by your recursive function calling itself too deeply. Instead of recursion use a loop.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to tell me how I should have asked a better question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The depth of the calls to `EncryptFields` in the stack over repeated runs looks something like this (where, for example, the first call to it is at depth 10):

```
10, 11, 12, ...
```

The depth of the calls to your EF query then look something like this:

```
11, 12, 13, ...
```

Suppose the maximum depth you're able to go to is N. Then when your call to `EncryptFields` is at depth N, it will try to call the EF query at depth N + 1. That is why you are getting the `StackOverflowException` inside of the EF query instead of directly in your recursive method `EncryptFields`.

This isn't an EF problem; the exception just happens to manifest itself there because your EF query leads your `EncryptFields` method in depth. The way to fix this is simply to eliminate the recursion.

```
private static void EncryptFields(IDBContext context, int batchSize, int maxRetries)
{
    while (true)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(maxRetries.ToString());
        if (maxRetries == 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        var phones = context.Phones
            .Where(p => !(p.Number == null || p.Number.Trim() == ""))
            .Take(batchSize)
            .ToList();

        if (phones.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (var phone in phones)
            {
                phone.Enc_Number = Encrypt(phone.Number);
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
            context.Dispose();
            context = new MyDBContext();
            context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

            maxRetries--;
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```